# Rails run code before every request before application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to run a piece of code in rails app before every request. Also, it should run before even reaching `application_controller.rb`.

I know that we can put such stuff in `config/initializers` or `application.rb`. But, I want to run this before every request.

Comment: What do you have to do?

Comment: Something like we put in a `before_filter` in application_controller. But, just that, this should run before the application controller is even invoked for the request.

Comment: Sorry for the typo earlier.

Comment: look into ActionController, you might put your code there

Comment: @downvoter, I know the question seem creepy. but there is really nothing else I can think of than this stupid hack. Also, the question is an over-simplistic view of the actual problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to write some [Rack Middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html). It's easy to do, here's a simple example which gets the subdomain for the purpose of multi tenant scoping:

```
class ClientSetup
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    Multitenant.current_tenant = Tenant.find_by_subdomain!(get_subdomain)
    @app.call(env)
  end

  private
    def get_subdomain
      host = @request.host
      return nil unless !(host.nil? || /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/.match(host))
      subdomain = host.split('.')[0..-3].first
      return subdomain unless subdomain == "www"
      return host.split('.')[0..-3][1]
    end
end
```

There's loads more examples around. You then need to add this class to your middleware stack with:

```
config.middleware.use 'ClientSetup'
```

in your `application.rb`.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a job for Rack middleware.  You can checkout the [Rails on Rack Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) and the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) for details.

So put something like the following in lib:

```
#lib/my_app_middleware.rb
class MyAppMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # place the code that you want executed on every request here
  end
end
```

And the following in config/application.rb to enable the middleware

```
config.middleware.use MyAppMiddleware
```

Check that its inserted ok:

```
rake middleware
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a subclass of ApplicationController that gets called when routing dispatches to one of your actions. That being said, if you really want to execute code before the controller is even called (before the before_filters ... etc) then you can modify the chain of middlewares in Rails like so:

```
config.middleware.insert_after(Rails::Rack::Logger, MyCustomMiddlewareClass)
```

You can read here for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#action-dispatcher-middleware-stack.

The example above may change depending on what you are trying to do.